# Buy Now Button PrestaShop - Attribute refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, prestashop

EDIT:

Working:

HTML >

```
   <div class="buton-cumpara-acum-test">
   <div class="buy-now">


 <button
            class="btn btn-primary add-to-cart"
           
            {if !$product.add_to_cart_url}
              disabled
            {/if}
          >
          
          <a href="{$link->getModuleLink('ps_buybuttonlite', 'RedirectManager')}?id_product={$product.id}&action=2{if $product.id_product_attribute}&id_product_attribute={$product.id_product_attribute}{/if}
">
            {l s='Cumpără acum' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}
            </a>
          </button>


   
    </div>   </div>
```

AND CUSTOM JS

```
prestashop.on('updatedProduct', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".buy-now").load(location.href + " .buy-now>*", "");
    }, 100)
});
```

I have made this Buy Now button on my website and works with number of items selected but how can I make it so it works with attribute selected without putting custom JS?

My code...

```
<div class="buton-cumpara-acum">
    
{if isset($static_token)}
<a class="button buy_now_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart',false, NULL, "add=1&id_product={$product->id|intval}&token={$static_token}", false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Buy Now'}" data-id-product="{$product->id|intval}"  onclick="this.href = this.href+ '&qty='+$('.buy_now_button').closest('form').find('#quantity_wanted').val() + '&ipa='+  $('.buy_now_button').closest('form').find('#idCombination').val(); " >
<span>{l s='Cumpără acum!'}</span>
</a>
{else}
<a class="button buy_now_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart',false, NULL, 'add=1&id_product={$product->id|intval}', false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Buy Now'}" data-id-product="{$product->id|intval}" onclick="this.href = this.href+ '&qty='+$('.buy_now_button').closest('form').find('#quantity_wanted').val() + '&ipa='+  $('.buy_now_button').closest('form').find('#idCombination').val(); " >
<span>{l s='Cumpără acum!'}</span>
</a></div>
{/if}
    {/block}  
  {/if}
</div><br>
```

to add in my code something like $product.id_product_attribute

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not really clear, where did you create this button: in theme/template files or in a custom module? What exactly do you need to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the interest! I want to add a buy now! 
I added here https://preturipebune.ro/auto/134-spuma-pentru-curaare-auto.html but if I have attributes the code made by me is only adding in cart and to checkout the first combination and I want the code to work with what is selected. Tried many variants but none worked so far..

Comment: I have made it to work. I will edit post